# Issue in exporting Date Time to TeraData using SQOOP

Tags: timestamp, export, teradata, sqoop, milliseconds

When I am trying to export a column value '2015-05-04 23:39:22.003168' to Teradata Table using SQOOP Export.
The Export was successful, but the data is loaded as '2015-05-04 23:39:22.000000'
The milliseconds are converted to ZEROs

The Data Type of the column in Teradata is Timestamp(6).
The Teradata connector used is: teradata-connector-1.4.0.jar

Here, how can I send milliseconds as it is to Teradata.

Regards,
D V N

Comment: Seems that while loading your teradata table the column data type is converted to timestamp(0) instead of timestamp(6). do not know whether timestamp(6) is supported for scoop export.

Comment: What I can think , load it to a temp table with that field as char(26) and then cast it that field to timestamp(6) to load it to main table.

Comment: Is there any way, we can find if timestamp is converted.

Comment: @Nithin can you paste you hdfs sample data [full row] , teradata table where you want to load and the query which you are using in case doing any update or so.

Answer (score 0):

@DV Nithin,

As anwaar suggested, try loading into a varchar(26) column in a Staging table. That is the general rule for data warehouse applications. And then use CAST to convert the datatype.

Sample sqoop command and DDL of the table will help us answer your query.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same situation by using:

```
cast('timestamp_var' as TIMESTAMP(6))
```

in the import query.

I know it sounds unnatural to cast timestamp(6) to a variable that is already a timestamp(6), but it worked out for me.